# how to solve this issue about InvalidClassException when deserializing objects from inputstream?

Tags: java, mysql, james

I am using james2.3.2 to be my mail server and the backend is mysql 5.5. 
I got a exception as the following:
23/06/11 16:39:49 DEBUG mailstore: Exception reading attributes Mail1308818378708-0-to-163.com in spool

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;; enum descriptor has non-zero serialVersionUID: 163864874655243298
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:789)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1534)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1591)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1299)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1910)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1834)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1067)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1812)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.james.mailrepository.JDBCMailRepository.retrieve(JDBCMailRepository.java:846)
    at org.apache.james.mailrepository.JDBCSpoolRepository.accept(JDBCSpoolRepository.java:203)
    at org.apache.james.mailrepository.JDBCSpoolRepository.accept(JDBCSpoolRepository.java:126)
    at org.apache.james.mailrepository.MailStoreSpoolRepository.accept(MailStoreSpoolRepository.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
    at $Proxy5.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.james.transport.JamesSpoolManager.run(JamesSpoolManager.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent 3 hours on testing with different databases,such as mysql 5.0 and oracle.It workes well on oracle but not on mysql.It seems it's the issue of mysql, not james.